# Pymongo: Send different operations to a server as one

Tags: python, pymongo

I know its possible to with separate statements, but is it possible to do the same with just one?

Something like this perhaps?

```
myquery = foo.insert_one(somedict), foo.delete_one(anotherdict), foo.replace_one(differendict)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using **bulk_write**

```
from pymongo import InsertOne, DeleteOne, ReplaceOne
requests = [InsertOne({'y': 1}), DeleteOne({'x': 1}),
             ReplaceOne({'w': 1}, {'z': 1}, upsert=True)]
result = db.test.bulk_write(requests)
```

More info you can find on the next page: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=bulk_write#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write